# What is the difference between Huggingface's `beam_search()`and `group_beam_search()`

Tags: huggingface-transformers

According to the documentation of Huggingface's `transformers` library, [`beam_search()`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.generation_utils.GenerationMixin.beam_search) and [`group_beam_search()`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.generation_utils.GenerationMixin.group_beam_search) are two methods to generate outputs from Encoder-Decoder models.
Both take the exact same input arguments, including batched sequence tensors, and generate outputs via beam search.

The question is therefore: what is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02424.pdf).